# Trying to execute a stored procedure in Oracle from PHP code

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I have already searched the web and the answers are always the same, with slight variations, but I have got no result.

In Oracle (Version 11.2.0.40), I wrote a stored procedure for testing, which only deletes records from a table, according to the argument passed. In PHP, via PDO, I created a connection and called the stored procedure, passing it the parameter to delete the records.

However, there is no answer, not even by error in CATCH.

As a test, I renamed the stored procedure in Oracle and ran PHP, which then accused the error that procedure did not exist, which would even be expected.

Below, the procedure and, below, the PHP code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
 p_PesquisaRateio (siglaUsuario IN VARCHAR2)
  AS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM RCR.CST_1410_RATEIO_CRGOMSIM WHERE USUARIO = siglaUsuario;
commit;
END;
```

-----Class method to prepare and to execute the procedure

```
public function passarParametro($sentencaCriacao,$siglaUsuario) {
  try {
    $sql_stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sentencaCriacao);
    $sql_stmt->bindParam(':siglaUsuario',$siglaUsuario);
    $sql_stmt->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $erro){
    echo "Não foi possivel excluir os dados do banco: ".$erro->getMessage();
  }
}
```

-----Preparing and calling the procedure

```
require("PDOConnection.php");
$dbh = new PDOConnection();
 $sentencaCriacao ="Call p_PesquisaRateio(:siglaUsuario)";
$dbh->passarParametro($sentencaCriacao,"'".$siglaUsuario."'");
```

----Testing in PLSQL Developer

```
begin
p_PesquisaRateio('MSIM' );
end;
```

The above execution is ok, data do deleted on table, but not via PHP.

Comment: Try to use full path to your stored procedure/function. I mean `package_name.proc_name` instead of just `proc_name`. Also, you need to be sure in settings of your database connection. It must be connected to the schema which has this package.

Comment: @AksenP this is a standalone stored procedure not a proc inside a package.

Comment: @hotfix, simply, package allows to make `grant on execution`. Without it can be an issue similar to this one. To create a package and put there proc-s/func-s you don't need to do something special.

Comment: @AksenP you can also grant a proc or func, no need to use a package :)

Comment: Thank you for the attention of all the people who answered my question.
I made a Package (PACK_MSIMRATEIO) according to Aksen's suggestion, and used the name of that Package - as in "BEGIN PACK_MSIMRATEIO.PesquisaRateioNovo(:siglaSocioResponsavel,:siglaUsuario); END;";- but still unanswered via PHP.

Comment: Thanks you all. Unfortunately, I had to abandon the project in this way, because the development cost is too high. It's not easy to use PHP in conjunction with Oracle, since Oracle, in its Procedures, doesn't make it easy for programmers to try to integrate different technologies in a simple way.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way. Feel free to contact me.  Next time, check out the resources such as my book http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html